# How are good UI libraries structured and what components are needed?

Tags: user-interface, arduino, embedded, stm32, esp32

Hello fellow developers,

So I'm working on a small project of mine with an STM32 where I need a display and I wanted to write the UI library from scratch to learn more stuff.

My question is: **How would you go on to write such UI library?**

The driver for the display is already ready.

What I need:

- A good and extensible menu system which is easy to use
- Button events
- Containers/Windows

I did a bit of research and from what I know now it is good to start with some kind of Window/Container component and then move to all the other types of widgets I need.

What do you think? How would you structure this kind of library/project? And how would you start?

I'm greatful for any help.
Kind regards ^^

Comment: The answer will vary widely depending on resources, and complexity.  UI solutions such as TouchGFX, LVGL or emWin are large, complex and resource hungry.  One reason you might want to implement your own is to avoid that, in which case the way they do it may be irrelevant.  Nonetheless, your question is better answered perhaps by looking at those implementations and thier documentation.  You won't get a better or different answer here.

Comment: Example: https://www.indes.com/files/producten/images/253/emwin_image2.gif. with more detail at https://www.indes.com/embedded/fr/products/253_emWin__Universal_GUI__and_Graphics_Software_/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may have already looked at this during your research.

Here are links for some popular UI's for java - both AWT and Swing :

[AWT](https://docs.oracle.com/javase%2F7%2Fdocs%2Fapi%2F%2F/java/awt/package-tree.html)
[Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase%2F7%2Fdocs%2Fapi%2F%2F/javax/swing/package-tree.html)

They give you a good example of the structure.

here is a developer's guide for LWUIT :

[LWUIT](https://docs.oracle.com/javame/dev-tools/lwuit-1.4/LWUIT_Developer_Guide.pdf)

LWUIT is a scaled down UI for Java ME (micro edition), so it gives you an idea of what is needed for a minimal UI.

My approach would be to start small, get it working and build up from there. This sounds obvious, but I am always amazed at how often it is not followed.

If you install and run java on your computer, you can see exactly how AWT or Swing works and look at the source code to get a better understanding.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
The resources you gave me to read are very good and well written.

I actually always do development in smaller steps. Especially for bigger projects.

Comment: Given the specified targets, is Java entirely relevant, if at all?

Comment: He was asking how to structure a UI library and I though AWT and Swing were good examples and easily available.

Comment: Are those examples documented down to the frame-buffer and device driver level, because for those targets that would be necessary.  Also why the question is itself far too broad.

Comment: Are those examples documented down to the frame-buffer and device driver level? Because for those targets that would be necessary. It is also why the question is itself far too broad.  I would have suggested something like https://www.indes.com/embedded/fr/products/253_emWin__Universal_GUI__and_Graphics_Software_/ as it describes a structure and is specifically for embedded systems. However it would be a link-only answer so disallowed.  Although this answer has _words_ around the links given, they are devoid of any content addressing the question directly, so is essentially also link-only.